# Constructing a UNIX path string on a windows system

Tags: java, string, io, path

I guess I'm not getting the full picture here, so I would appreciate someone's help.

I'm using java.nio.file.path and java.nio.file.paths. I'm trying to make a path string from subcomponents using something like `Path pt = Paths.get("/this/", "is", "a", "file", "path");` but it's `.toString()` function is using backslashes since I'm on windows `\this\is\a\file\path`. The problem is I want UNIX separators and can't find a way to force it without wrapping it with a `substituteSlashes(pt.toString());` function. This isn't ideal and I'd rather just go back to hard-coding paths in strings.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to get an UNIX path on Windows ? Reading the documentation, the separator depends of the system on which you run your program (by the function FileSystem.getSeparator()), so you can't directly get UNIX path on windows by this method.

Comment: `FileSystem.getSeparator()` returns the separator between file names in a Path, not the separator used between directories/subdirectories in a single file name. For UNIX this is a colon, and on Windows it is a semicolon.

Comment: I'm using generating commands to be run at a later time on a different system. I might be misunderstanding the use of the Path class. The only reason I'm using it is to prevent something like this from happening. `String path = "/home/" + "user-dir" + "file.ext";` `path is "/home/user-dirfile.ext"`

Comment: When you will run your program on an UNIX system, it will work well and use the UNIX separator, which is '/' . Path.get() gives you the path you ask to it, on the platform you are running the program.